# One way data binding values do not show up, however data is shown when console logged

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an API running in the background using visual studio ASP.NET Core. I then created an Angular 8 application which is supposed to consume the API. In the past it was working when I was using separate folders (solutions). However I am now required to use the same solution/project. That is where the issue started. Below is a typical example of what happens:

[image]

Basically it is calling the API however the binding is the issue.

**Service.ts**

```
getPolicies(): Observable<StagingPrepPolicies[]> {
    return this.http.get<StagingPrepPolicies[]>(this.rootUrl + '/StagingPrepPolicyDatas');
```

**component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PoliciesDataServiceService } from '../shared/policies-data-service.service';
import { StagingPrepPolicies } from '../shared/staging-prep-policies';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-policy-data-list',
  templateUrl: './policy-data-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./policy-data-list.component.css']
})
export class PolicyDataListComponent implements OnInit {
  config: any;
  policies = [];

  constructor(
    private policiesService: PoliciesDataServiceService) {
    }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.policiesService.getPolicies().subscribe(data => {
      this.policies = data;
      console.log(this.policies)
    });

    this.config = {
      itemsPerPage: 10,
      currentPage: 1,
      totalItems: this.policies.length
    };
  }

  pageChanged(event) {
    this.config.currentPage = event;
  }

}
```

**component.html**

---

```
<tbody>
      <tr
        *ngFor="let item of policies | paginate: config"
      >
        <td>{{ item.ClientReferenceNumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.POFirstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.DateOfSale }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

---

Comment: Can you show us also StagingPrepPolicies

Comment: It is a large interface file around 226 lines of mostly string variables

Comment: Can you please show the whole component.ts?

Comment: Have added the full component.ts to original question.

Comment: I think you just write the properties in a wrong way like DateOfSale I think should be dateOfSale I see in your console all properties start with a small letter.

Comment: You were right. edited the html from DateOfSale to dateOfSale. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer that requires the interpolation syntax converted from 
{{ item.ClientReferenceNumber }} to {{ item.clientReferenceNumber }}.

Basically it requires to have the same syntax as the output JSON.